# Laravel: I cant upload videos

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload videos using Laravel. I get following error:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 17500298 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

I changed param in php.ini of my xampp local server:

```
upload_max_filesize
```

But I get the same error as shown above.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel. It's your php.ini setting and settings in your webserver that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix these values inside php.ini first

```
upload_max_filesize = ??M
post_max_size = ??M
```

and then make

```
dd(phpinfo());
```

somewhere in your code and see where is that php.ini file your server uses

[image]

and if those values are applied!

[image]